# Trying to implement ctrl z option in windows form

Tags: c#, image, winforms

I have been trying to implement a ctrl z feature in my mini paint application.
The problem is that for the picture box side of things, it doesn't work. At the the beggining of the mouse up event before the new drawing, I save the current picture box image in a stack and when I press ctrl z, I pop that image and save it in the picture box image. The problem is that it always saves the new modified image in the stack not the previous one even if I saved it technically before the new updates (at the begining of the mouse up event).

A snippet of the code

```
void key(object sender, KeyEventArgs e){

...
else if (  e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z) {
    
   if (save.Count > 0) {  
                    //trying to save the previous image                                       
                    pictureBox9.Image = save.Peek() as Image;   
                    drawArea = save.Pop() as Bitmap;
                    pictureBox9.Image = drawArea;
                    g1 = Graphics.FromImage(drawArea);
                   // pictureBox9.Refresh();
                }
    }
}

 private void pictureBox9_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
     save.push(pictureBox9.Image);   

     //save is the stack and that should be the current image      
     ....
}
```

Comment: It seems that you push to stack and pop from it always same instance of image. When pushing you need to make copy of image.

Comment: BTW, it's a common trap to do custom drawing directly into a `PictureBox`.  _["Typically the PictureBox is used to display graphics from a bitmap, metafile, icon, JPEG, GIF, or PNG file."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.picturebox?view=net-5.0#remarks)_.  Instead you might want to consider creating a your own type derived from `Control`.  This gives complete control over rendering and and knowledge over how it is driven

Comment: The copy idea ,ive tried before and it didnt work.I copied the bitmap ,pushed it on stack and then popped but nothing

Comment: Edit,my problem was solved by indeed saving a clone